# Setting image to Navigation bar backbutton in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

How to set Image for navigation bar backbutton in iOS

Can anybody tell exact size of the image i have to use.

Thanks

Comment: use this link fine for u http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23881773/how-to-place-a-uiimage-in-navigationbar-such-that-its-a-logo/23881868#23881868

Comment: try the above link it work fine and correct image size is 20 x 20

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I show a custom image in navigation bar back button instead of default buttons which are shown by nav bar itself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1213843/how-can-i-show-a-custom-image-in-navigation-bar-back-button-instead-of-default-b)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIImage* image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button.png"];
CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(15,5, 25,25);
UIButton *someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg];
[someButton setBackgroundImage:image3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(Back_btn:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[someButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
UIBarButtonItem *mailbutton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =mailbutton;
[someButton release];
```

Comment: its working i want to set frame for backbutton like this CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(25,5, 25,25); but its not working any idea?

Comment: I want to set frame for backbutton which i am adding image

Comment: means change width on button ?

Answer (score 1):

If your app is targeted for iOS 7+ and you're only looking to change the back arrow, this may be the quickest solution:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"];
```

It's up to you what the dimensions are; though I wouldn't make it much smaller than the default back image.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your requirement...
**self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:<#(UIImage *)#> style:<#(UIBarButtonItemStyle)#> target:<#(id)#> action:<#(SEL)#>**